# Is there a way to replace URL Link of Text in Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs-api

I started exploring Google Docs API in Python. It does pretty much everything I want it to do except for one thing.

I can replace the text of a document but I can't change the value of the hyperlinks.

Meaning if a link looks like this : [a link](http://www.example.com/), I can change the value of the text `a link` but not the target URL.

I've been going through the documentation but I can't find anything about it. Could it be a missing feature or am I missing the way to do that?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the hyperlink using UpdateTextStyleRequest of the batchupdate method in Google Docs API. At this time, please set the property of `Link` of `TextStyle`.

#### Endpoint

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{file ID}:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body:

```
{
 "requests": [
  {
   "updateTextStyle": {
    "textStyle": {
     "link": {
      "url": "https://sampleUrl"  # Please set the modified URL here.
     }
    },
    "range": {
     "startIndex": 1,
     "endIndex": 2
    },
    "fields": "link"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

#### Note:

- From your question, I could understand that you have already used Google Docs API and you can modify the text of the link text. I think that you can modify the link using above request body and the script you have.

#### References:

- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest)
- [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TextStyle)
- [Link](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Link)

If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You want to retrieve the text with the hyperlink.

From your reply comment, I could understand like above. When my understanding is correct, you can retrieve it using `documents.get` method. In this case, when `fields` is used, the response become to easily read.

#### Endpoint:

```
GET https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{file ID}?fields=body(content(paragraph(elements(endIndex%2CstartIndex%2CtextRun(content%2CtextStyle%2Flink%2Furl)))))
```

- In this endpoint, `body(content(paragraph(elements(endIndex,startIndex,textRun(content,textStyle/link/url)))))` is used as `fields`.

#### Sample response:

For example, when the following texts are put in a Google Document and `def` has a hyperlink,

```
abc
def
```

The response is as follows. From the following result, you can retrieve the position of text with the hyperlink can be retrieved. Using this, you can modify the hyperlink.

```
{
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {},
      {
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 1,
              "endIndex": 5,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "abc\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 5,
              "endIndex": 8,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "def",
                "textStyle": {
                  "link": {
                    "url": "https://sample/"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "startIndex": 8,
              "endIndex": 9,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in answering. Thank you for the time you spent on trying to figure that out :)

So long story short, although it's the right code to change the formatting of text to link format, it's lacking the feature of finding and replacing existing text. As it is right now, I have to first find at which character the text I want to replace the link of starts and end (The startIndex and endIndex in your example).

So that's the challenge now, I will update my question as soon as I get to really work on it but I'm sure there's an okay-ish way to proceed :)

Comment: @Yaniss Illoul Thank you for replying. You can retrieve the position of text with the hyperlink using ``documents.get``. About this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

`batchUpdate` requires to know position of text, we can get document with all content and find positions of links

In my case I implement it as:

1. Copy template to new place with final name
2. Replace link texts and other parts of text
3. Get document
4. Find links positions in doc
5. Update link URLs

Here example in nodejs

```js
const {google, docs_v1} = require('googleapis');

async function replaceInDoc(doc) {
  let documentId = 'some doc id'
  let auth = 'auth value for user'
  let linkNewUrl = 'https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client'

  google.options({auth: auth})
  var docs = new docs_v1.Docs({}, google)

  // document should have link with http://repo-url.com text, we will update it

  var requests = [
    {
      replaceAllText: {
        containsText: {
          text: 'http://repo-url.com',
          matchCase: true,
        },
        replaceText: linkNewUrl,
      },
    }
  ]

  var updateRes = await docs.documents.batchUpdate({
    documentId: documentId,
    resource: {
      requests: requests,
    },
  });

  var docInfo = await docs.documents.get({documentId: documentId})
  var linkPos = findLinksInDoc(docInfo)

  // set new url to link by position of link in the document
  var requests = [
    {
      updateTextStyle: {
        textStyle: {
          link: {
            url: linkNewUrl
          }
        },
        range: {
          startIndex: linkPos[linkNewUrl][0],
          endIndex: linkPos[linkNewUrl][1]
        },
        fields: "link"
      }
    }
  ]

  var updateRes = await docs.documents.batchUpdate({
    documentId: documentId,
    resource: {
      requests: requests,
    },
  });
}

// returns hash as { 'http://example.com': [startPosition, endPosition] }
function findLinksInDoc(doc) {
  var links = {}

  doc.data.body.content.forEach(section => {
    if (section.paragraph) {
      section.paragraph.elements.forEach(element => {
        if (element.textRun && element.textRun.textStyle.link) {
          links[element.textRun.content] = [element.startIndex, element.endIndex]
        }
      })
    }
  })

  return links
}
```

Comment: Is it only me find google APIs are difficult to use?