# Im looking for a way to mass find/replace hyperlinks in a google drive file

Tags: python, json, hyperlink, google-drive-api, cloud

Im currently performing a migration of data from Box to Google drive. Most of these files contain links that reference, and then take the user to, other files within the box drive.

However, when i do eventually migrate the files to google drive, the old links will break and become obsolete as the previous location in Box will no longer exist.

Writing a find/replace script that updates the strings wont work as although the string changes the URL_link attached to it stays the same, does anybody have any suggestions? I can't seem to find anything about this in the google API.

I had the idea of breaking the link, updating the string, and then making it a link again. But once again, i can't seem to find how to create a link from a string in the API.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by links.  Are these links in the files themselves?  you would need to use the google docs api to edit documents to update things.   The google drive api is just a file storage system.

Comment: yes, links in the files themselves, that direct to other files within the drive. I've looked through the google docs API too and can't see any mention of links

Comment: I have never heard of creating a link in a file to a file on drive.  not if its not supported in drive then docs api wont be able to do it either.   docs api is very limited

Comment: really ? maybe im explaining it badly. atm its just a hyperlink/url pointing to another file in the drive. i've actually found some information here https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Link                         
      "link": {
                object (Link)           not sure how to apply that though, it says Setting a link on a text range that overlaps with an existing link will also update the existing link to point to the new URL.

Comment: What is the type of files that contain the links? Are they docs after been migrated to google drive? If you you could just get the link in the body inside the doc and replace it by the url of the Google Drive file it is supposed to be linking to.

Comment: the file types are mainly documents before migration, and will remain as docs after. Yes, thats what im trying to do, however the migration is going to be TB's of data, with thousands of broken links. So doing it manually will take a lot of time, which is why i have been researching building a script to at least semi-automise it.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution / Workaround

You can automate this using the Google APIs. These are the following steps I would follow to achieve what you are aiming for here:

1. Migrate the files to Google Drive (this will convert your documents into Google Doc files that then you can access with the Gooogle Docs API. Do this by specifying the MIME type in the metadata when doing the migration. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) you can see how to specify this and upload using the Google Drive API.
2. Once you have all your desired files uploaded to Drive as docs, you will get their body and look for the links in order to replace them. You can access the links by accessing the body element inside the document element, for more information with regards to this [check this link](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) and explore the nested objects. Perform a find replace on the body to change the URL of the document.

> If you have issues regarding the change of attached links as you mentioned in your question, check out [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55545395/12835757) that addresses this problems.

3. Change the link by updating the document following the instructions stated in the above Stack Overflow Question and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)